# REALM MOBILE PLATFORM sync problems resolution

Tags: swift3, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have linked list in Realm DB like

ABCD

Each item is Realm object like

{name,next item}

So if I change list on device 1 offline to

ACBD

and on device 2 to

ADBC

and sync after that I get synced DB but wrong cycled list

A -> D -> B -> D .....

How can I solve this problem?

Is there possibility to get synced objects after sync on clients and to correct lists before realm Results notifications will be launched?

Update.

I also tried to use such model for hierarchical lists

```
class MList: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let items = List<MItem>()
}

class MItem: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let subitems = List<MItem>()
}
```

I have used data

```
A
B

1.
A
-B

2.
B
-A
```

After sync but list lost all items. So such data struct is unsuitable for my task.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I see the problem.

Manually maintaining a linked list structure unfortunately won't work, because Realm sees each link update as a regular property update without knowledge about the item's position in the list. Therefore the list updates cannot be merged in the expected way when multiple participants update the list, and the result will be duplicates, cycles, or leaked objects.

Instead, I suggest you use Realm's built-in list type, which will merge correctly. You will still have a problem related to the `parent` field in your data model, whereby if two participants change the value, the last one to do so will "win". I'm not sure what your exact use case is, so this may or may not be fine. Notably it probably won't be fine if you perform tree rotations, in which case you will end up leaking objects from the graph or creating unexpected cycles.

The best long-term solution is for Realm to introduce a proper CRDT tree type, but so far there hasn't been demand for this. If trees are a fundamentally requirement in your data model, I suggest creating a feature request for CRDT trees in [our GitHub repository](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues).

Comment: I think manual conflict resolution is more universal way to work with sync problems. I have got answer to my question in [link](https://forums.realm.io/t/sync-tree-structures/122) with example of manual conflict resolution. But is there a way to get a list of synced objects in manual conflict resolution function? Because checking the entire database is too expensive.

Comment: So it will be helpful to have a time for manual sync resolution before Realm Results update notifications will be launched. Otherwise Realm Results notifications will be dangerous.

Comment: Realm Mobile Platform currently relies on automatic conflict resolution to enable offline mode. Manual conflict resolution may be added in the future, but it does disagree with offline-first operation, because every participant is no longer guaranteed to agree on how to resolve a conflict. Instead, we advocate expressing the desired behavior in the data model such that automatic conflict resolution knows to do the right thing. There is a little bit of information on this in our documentation: https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#conflict-resolution

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Realm's own lists? They have quite an elaborate merging logic that supports element moves/reorderings: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#list-properties

Comment: Yes for flat lists integrated Realm lists work good. Sync happens without problem. But I have hierarchical lists in my app really. In this case there are same problems. I need to create post sync logic before update notifications.

Comment: A hierarchical list is often called a tree :)If you'll explain your data model we could try to fit it into Realm data structures.

Comment: Now I have such model 
`
    class MList: Object {
        dynamic var name = ""
        dynamic var firstItem: PLItem?
    }
`
class MItem: Object {
    
    dynamic var name = ""
    
    dynamic var next: PLItem?
    
    dynamic var list: PLList?
    
    dynamic var parent: PLItem?
}

Answer (score 0):

Now I have the model

> ```
> class MList: Object {
>     dynamic var name = ""
>     dynamic var firstItem: PLItem?
> }
>
> class MItem: Object {
>     dynamic var name = ""
>     dynamic var next: PLItem?
>     dynamic var parent: PLItem?
> }
> ```

I use "next" to order list and "parent" to create the tree structure.

Comment: No, this is answer to @VictorGrishchenko. I am beginner at stackoverflow so may be my answer is not clean enough.

Comment: Don't post answers to give more information. Either edit your original post, or write a comment.